# Use Time Series to Predict the Next Event in a Series

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a set of data that is the maximum amount of ice on a lake, and the first date that a boat is seen on the lake. I want to use a time series to predict, based on the amount of ice on the lake this year, when the first boat will be seen on the lake this year. My data looks like:

```
Date    Percent Ice
2018-4-12   69.8
2017-4-2    73.6
2016-4-3    64.9
2015-4-13   31.3
2014-5-7    96
2013-3-30   92.5
```

I'm not so familiar with time series functions, so the best code I have so far is simply importing modules and reading in my data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv('boats.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('boats.csv', nrows = 47)
```

Comment: There are way too many ways of doing this for us to give you the "right" answer. What sort of method are you looking for? A spline curve which you can extrapolate from? Autoregression? A recurrent neural net? I'd suggest you look into those methods yourself and decide what works for you, then come back when you have questions about implementation.

Comment: You can find a forecasting methodology here: https://towardsdatascience.com/an-end-to-end-project-on-time-series-analysis-and-forecasting-with-python-4835e6bf050b

However, I agree with Jordan – it would be better for you to look into different methodologies and learn which is the best for the problem you are trying to solve (the boiled down version of the problem you're presenting is too general to give an opinion on).